# ATG Search. Sorting results by value in map

Tags: java, sorting, atg

I need to sort search results by product rating. 
Rating is contained in `Map<String, String>`, where the key is **Site** ID and the value is a String in format **"Rating: 5.0; Reviews: 1"**. 
So, as I think, I need to add this map to properties in `product-catalog-output-config.xml` to index it. 
But how to tell ATG Search to take a value by the key from map?
Or, maybe, there are some alternatives?

Comment: This is probably not doable the way you think. Save for a few specialized cases, a `Map` offers no guarantee as to the order of its entries. There are solutions, of course, but they will largely depend on the version of Java you use here. Also, it is unclear what your final goal is. Code?

Comment: Are you talking about ATG Search (as in prior to version 10.1.2) or about Endeca?

Comment: @radimpe ATG Search. I'm using ATG 10.0.2

Answer (score 0):

One way to support would be to use a custom GenerativePropertyAccessor which dynamically generates a map that contains the siteId/rating combinations you want to have included in the index. The key would be the name of the property to be indexed, the value would be the rating. This single property could be configured in the output config and generate zero or more properties to be indexed with whatever name/values you programtically decide to include.